# share a post on linkedin using linkedin javascript api

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee

This code is supposed to share a link on LinkedIn, but for some reason it's not working - I'm not sure why. Can anyone help?

```
   <!-- NOTE: be sure to set onLoad = onLinkedInLoad -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function onLinkedInLoad() {
      IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", function() {onLinkedInLogin();});
    IN.Event.on(IN, "logout", function() {onLinkedInLogout();});
    }




  function onLinkedInLogout() {
    // do nothing
 }

 function onLinkedInLogin() {
   IN.Event.on("shareAPI", "click", doSharingTest);
   }

     function doSharingTest() {
         IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares")
         .method("POST")
             .body( JSON.stringify( {
            "content": {
               "submitted-url": "http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/jsapi-console",
             "title": "JSAPI Console",
         "description": "JSAPI Developer Console",
           "submitted-image-url":           "http://developer.linkedin.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/102-1101-13-1003/30-25/LinkedIn_Logo30px.png"
     },
       "visibility": {
      "code": "anyone"
      },
    "comment": "This is a test posting from the LinkedIn JSAPI Console"
   })
 )
.result(function(r) { 
  alert("POST OK");
})
.error(function(r) {
  alert("POST FAIL");
});
   }
```

I got this code from http://developer.linkedinlabs.com. I have registered my application on the LinkedIn developer network. Can anybody tell me is this right code, or do I need to modify anything?